# Can I cancel a hotel booking after receiving my Dubai visa?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, bookings, hotels, dubai

I booked a hotel in Dubai and mentioned it on my visa application. I now wish to stay with a friend of mine instead. Is it safe to cancel the booking right now, or would doing so impact my visa application as I would no longer be staying where I said I would be? Should I instead cancel it after I go through immigration? I don’t find living in a hostel safe anymore.

Comment: Did the hotel sponsor your visa?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold.